# Problem in calculating checksum : casting int to signed int32

Tags: python, casting, checksum

I need to convert the following c code (to calculate checksum for a file) to python. I had written, the corresponding code in python but the result didn't match the c version. The problem was that python autmatically promotes int to long whenever overflow occurs and this results in wrong checksums.

Any idea how to overcome this problem ? or is there a python function that converts long to signed int32 ?

Thanks

```
int calcChecksum(const guchar *data, gsize len)
{ 

    const guchar *p = data;
    int checksum = 0, g, i = len;

    while(i--) {
            checksum = (checksum << 4) + *p++;

            if((g = (checksum & 0xf0000000)) != 0)
                    checksum ^= g >> 23;

            checksum &= ~g;
    }
    return checksum;
}
```

Solution:

Thanks for all the help. Here's the function that worked for me -

```
 def int32(x):
    x = 0xffffffff & x
    if x > 0x7fffffff :
        return - ( ~(x - 1) & 0xffffffff )
    else : return x
```

Comment: Isn't there something missing in the c code? data / p seems to be used in a very odd way...

Comment: Sorry, had accidently removed '+' during formatting. Corrections made . thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.int32`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html?highlight=int32#array-types-and-conversions-between-types) or `numpy.uint32` if you need to restrict the range. Or mod it by `1 << 32` after operations that could "overflow".

Comment: Or `& 0xFFFFFFFF` (`& ((1<<32)-1)`).  I happen to like that more, but it does the exact same as `% (1 << 32)`.

Comment: Its not just about extracting the lower 32 bits, but the sign also needs to be considered - the way java handle the overflow.
e.g. int i = 0xffffffff; system.out.println(i) would give -1.