# Python Bitshift 32 Bit Constraint

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem in calculating checksum : casting int to signed int32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300740/problem-in-calculating-checksum-casting-int-to-signed-int32)

This should be a relatively easy answer, I just don't really know how to search for it...I got a few semi-relevant [things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210629/python-unsigned-32-bit-bitwise-arithmetic), but nothing that fits what I'm trying to do.

```
>>> 1171855803 << 7
149997542784L # I want -326312576
```

In other words, treat the number as an integer and don't allow it to convert to a long.
How would I do this?

I tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2300740/problem-in-calculating-checksum-casting-int-to-signed-int32):

```
>>> x = 0xFFFFFFFF & (1171855803 << 7)
>>> if x > 0x7FFFFFFF: print -(~(x - 1) & 0xFFFFFFFF)
else: print x

-326312576L # yay!
```

It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not be the best answer, but this works...

```
import numpy as np
np.int32(1171855803) << 7
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
import ctypes
a=ctypes.c_int32(1171855803)
a.value<<=7
print a
```

which gives: c_int(-326312576)

It seems to allow platform specific bit-manipulations. I am not sure about efficiency.